# Avoid auto truncation of string with spaces and double quotes in shell

Tags: string, shell, truncate

How to avoid auto truncation of shell string which have double quotes and spaces.?

```
BUILD_CMD="mk test -args "KEEP_OBJ=yes TEST1=no TEST2=yes""
echo "$BUILD_CMD"
```

Expected result : mk test -args KEEP_OBJ=yes TEST1=no TEST2=yes
Actual result : mk test -args KEEP_OBJ=yes

I know this can be achieved with adding escape char '\'

```
BUILD_CMD="mk test -args "KEEP_OBJ=yes\ TEST1=no\ TEST2=yes""
```

The problem is that the BUILD_CMD itself is taken from cli input without any escape char and in script I need take the input as it is as given by user and run it

Comment: Relevan: [BashFAQ/050](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

Comment: Notice that this `foo="part one "part two""` is leaving `part two` *unquoted*. To nest double quotes, you have to escape the inner ones: `foo="part one \"part two\""`, but since you get the string handed to you, start looking into arrays, specifically `"$@"`.

Comment: As noted in BASHFAQ/050, your best bet is to load everything into an array.

Comment: Escaping only applies to string literals. If you are reading the data from somewhere, escaping is not and cannot be your responsibility.

Comment: How do you mean _the BUILD_CMD itself is taken from cli input_?